# How to add a marker to .png map image on Windows Phone?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, dictionary, marker

I have a Windwows Phone application that allows the user to see on the map his initial position acquired by scanning a qr code. When user scans Qr Code, he gets the url to the map stored in the web server and the X and Y coordinates of his initial position.

I've created a container of map image in .xaml page :

```
<Image x:Name="ImagePanel" Width="470" Margin="5,0,5,98" Grid.Row="1" />
```

In .cs page, I downloaded map image from server :

```
    public void DownloadImage(string URLmappa)
    {

        ImagePanel.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(URLmappa));

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);

        try
        {

            wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URLmappa), wc);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
          }

    }


    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)  
            {  
               if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)  
              {  
                  try  
                  {  
                     BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();  
                     image.SetSource(e.Result);  
                     ImagePanel.Source = image;  
                  }  
                  catch (Exception ex)  
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                  }  
              }  
              else  
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("It's impossibile to download map from server");
              }  

                    }
```

...and it works but the hard part is marking the locations on the image (report).

I've found something like this :

```
    public void MarkLocation(int posizioneX, int posizioneY)
    {
var imageMarker = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image { ImageUrl = "/pin.jpg" };
imageMarker.Style.Value = string.format("position:absolute;top:{0}px;left:{1}px;display:block;width:30px; height:30px;", point.X, point.Y);
imagePanel.Controls.Add(imageMarker); }
```

but it doesn't work on Windows Phone.

I'm interested in suggestions on how to mark location on (over) the image given X,Y coordinates.

Alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the image on a canvas and position a marker element absolutely as you are trying to do with the webcontrol.  Alternatively, you could write the marker on the image using [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll follow your advice.